# RASA and spaCy only display intents as letters, not words

Tags: python, spacy, rasa

for my voice assistant I am using my own code with RASA and spacy. Hereby, the voice assistant saves a story, composed of the complete text (utterance), intents (from RASA) and entities (from spaCy). However, the data in the JSON file displays the intents per letter but not at a word. Do you know what's wrong here?

JSON:

`{"username": "Mia", "utterance": "i want on a vacation",  "intents": ["v", "a", "c", "a", "t", "i", "o", "n"], "entities": []`

Code:

```
from html import entities
import pyttsx3
import json
import speech_recognition as sr 
import datetime
import requests
import pandas as pd
import spacy


STORIES_FILE = "stories_2.json"
stories = []
with open(STORIES_FILE) as stories_file:
    stories = json.load(stories_file)

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")

# setting up engine to Pyttsx3 for text to speech in Python
engine = pyttsx3.init()
engine.runAndWait()

now = datetime.datetime.now()

# both scripts (prototpe 3 and rasa) are running simulatensoly
def rasa(utterance):
    """
    Takes an utterance and requests rasa to classify it to one of the trained intents.
    Assumes RASA is running on port 5005 with API enabled.
    """
    data = {"text":utterance, "message_id":"0"}
    response = requests.post(url="http://localhost:5005/model/parse", json = data)
    rasa_intents = response.json()
    return rasa_intents

#create an empty list to store information of conversation
def save_story(stories, username, utterance, intents, entities):
    """
    Saves a story, composed of the complete text (utterance), intents (from RASA) and entities (from Spacy).
    Saved to a file parsed as JSON, as an item of a list.
    """
    stories.append({
        "username":username, 
        "utterance":utterance, 
        "timestamp":str(datetime.datetime.now()),
        "intents":intents,
        "entities":entities
        })
    with open(STORIES_FILE, "w") as stories_file:
        json.dump(stories, stories_file)

def speak(audio):
    """
    Allows the device to speak audio to the user.
    """
    engine.say(audio)
    engine.runAndWait()
    print(audio)


def takeCommand():
    """
    Listens for user input using the microphone.
    After utterance is recognised, the sentences are sent to RASA to determine any intents that were mentioned.
    All text is tokenized and spacy attempts to recognize any entities.
    Utterance, intents and entities are returned.
    """
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        print("Listening...")
        r.pause_threshold = 1
        audio = r.listen(source)
  
    try:
        print("Recognizing...")   
        utterance = r.recognize_google(audio, language ='en-US')
        print(f"User said: {utterance}\n")
        doc = nlp(utterance)
        story_intents = []

        for sentence in doc.sents:
            intents = rasa(str(sentence))
            story_intents += intents["intent"]["name"]
        entities = []
        for named_entity in doc.ents:
            entities.append(named_entity.label_, named_entity.lemma_)


    except Exception as e:
        print(e)   
        speak("My apologies, I did not understand that. Could you please say that again?")
        return "None"
     
    return utterance, story_intents, entities


def wishMe():
    """
    Greets the user by speaking the appropriate greeting based on the time of day.
    """
    hour = int(datetime.datetime.now().hour)

    if hour>= 0 and hour<12:
        speak("Good Morning!")
  
    elif hour>= 12 and hour<18:
        speak("Good Afternoon!")  
  
    else:
        speak("Good Evening!") 
  
    assistantname =("Anna")
    speak("I am your personal storykeeper, " + assistantname)

    
def get_username():
    """
    Small intent to get to know the user by asking his/her name.
    Speaks the question and opens the mic to let the user answer.
    The answer is saved as the name of the user (username) in memory of the script.
    """
    speak("I would love to know more about you, so let's start off right away. What's your name?")
    username, intents, entities = takeCommand()
    speak("Nice to meet you " + username + ".")
    #columns = shutil.get_terminal_size().columns
     
    #print("Welcome", username.center(columns))
    return username
    
def storykeepergoal():
    """
    Determines whether or not the user wants to tell a story.
    Speaks the question and listens for input from the user using takeCommand()
    """
    speak("Would you like to know more about my goal to conserve your family's stories?")
    utterance,intents, entities = takeCommand() #All the commands said by user will be stored here in 'utterance' and will be converted to lower case for easily recognition of command
    utterance = utterance.lower()
    if "yes" in utterance:
        speak("Happy that you are interested to learn more about me. You've probably experienced the moment at a family's birthday party when it's all about telling stories from when you were little, or a funny story about a vacation. As life goes on, those stories might be forgotten or cannot be told anymore. This is where I come in - by telling me stories about your favourite moments in life, I can store these forever. Your family can do the same thing.")
        return True
    else:
        speak("Alright, no problem.")
        return False

def getstory(stories, username):
    """
    Asks the user to tell their story using takeCommand()
    """
    speak("I am curious to hear what memories and stories you have about your family. Please tell me your favourite memory with, or about your family.")

    utterance, intents, entities = takeCommand() #All the commands said by user will be stored here in 'utterance' and will be converted to lower case for easily recognition of command
    utterance = utterance.lower()
    save_story(stories, username, utterance, intents, entities)


def run_conversation():
    """
    Runs the whole conversation by running the intents one by one.
    """
    wishMe() #greet the user
    username = get_username() #ask the user his/her name
    user_wants_to_tell_story = storykeepergoal() #ask the user whether they want to tell a story
    getstory(stories, username) #ask for the story


run_conversation()
```

Comment: When you pass the `sentence` in `takeComman` method, what do you get after `rasa_intents = response.json()`?

Answer (score 0):

In the function takeCommand():

```
story_intents += intents["intent"]["name"]
# story_intents: ["v", "a", "c", "a", "t", "i", "o", "n"]
```

You are storing characters instead of the full intents.

```
example_list = []
example_list += "test"
print(example_list) 
# ['t', 'e', 's', 't']
```

You should append the intent to the list:

```
story_intents.append(intents["intent"]["name"])
```